# for loop and if loop is refusing to print a varriable outside the loop?

Tags: php

i am facing a problem that after i created the jQuery post, i was able to receive all the data but as a one peace, so when i began rephrasing them i succeed until the final part which was the inserting into the database, where inside the for loop and if loop i am getting the value but when i wanted to start inserting them into the database i am getting null values, below is the for loop and if loop

```
if ($action == "insert")
{
    $fields = explode("&",$data);

    foreach($fields as $field)
    {
        $field_key_value = explode("=",$field);
        $key = urldecode($field_key_value[0]);
        $value = urldecode($field_key_value[1]);

        $id = $row['id'];

        $date1 = date("d/n/Y");

        foreach ($cart->get_contents() as $item)
        {
            $item_id    = $item['id'];
            $item_name  = $item['name'];
            $item_price = $item['price'];
            $item_qty   = $item['qty'];
            $item_ids       = explode("-",$item_id);

            for($i = 0; $i < count($item_ids); $i++)
            {
                $item_idn = join("",$item_ids);
            }

            if($key == $item_id."id")
            {
                $ids = $value;
                echo $ids."\r\n";
            }
            elseif($key == "Small".$item_idn)
            {
                $small= $value;
                echo $small."\r\n";
            }
            elseif($key == "large".$item_idn)
            {
                $large= $value;
                echo $large."\r\n";
            }
            elseif($key == "medium".$item_idn)
            {
                $medium= $value;
                echo $medium."\r\n";
            }
            elseif($key == "xlarge".$item_idn)
            {
                $xlarge= $value;
                echo $xlarge."\r\n";
            }
            elseif($key == "qty".$item_idn)
            {
                $qty = $value;
                echo $qty."\r\n";
            }
            elseif($key == "Total".$item_idn)
            {
                $subtotal = $value;
                echo $subtotal."\r\n";
            }
            elseif($key == "finaltotal")
            {
                $finaltotal = $value.",";
                $final = explode(",",$finaltotal);

                for($i = 0; $i < count($final); $i++)
                {
                    $totalf = $final[$i];
                    break 3;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `$value` and why do you append a `,` at it's end?

Comment: what variable are you trying to print?

Comment: please provide more information and code (and format it properly). I don't get what the exact problem is from your description.

Comment: because $value is an array contains a mixed data of all my form, so i wanted to split all these data to its respective variable so that i can be easier to be inserted into the database

Comment: You cannot explode an array even more you cannot append a string to an array.

Comment: i used jQuery serialized to fetch all the form and send them through post, and when i received it i got an array, and i have to split each data to its respective variable everything went fine but my problem now is inserting them into the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/):

> The .serialize() method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation

So on the PHP side you'll get a similar string like this:

`a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4&e=5`

There's no need to explode `&`'s (or any other hocus-pocus) you can easily access your submitted variables like:

`$a = $_POST['a']; //1`

<sub>Of course when you submit your data via `$_GET`, you need to use `$_GET`.</sub>

Comment: hey there @fabrik when i tested your method i keep on getting null

Comment: What you get when you do print_r($_POST) on the PHP side?

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if you have a number of issues. If your jQuery is posting to your PHP script you can get all your keys/values through the $_POST array. You could get $finaltotal like this `$finaltotal = $_POST['finaltotal']`. If your jQuery is not POSTing, but sending them as a GET request, you can get the same value like so `$finaltotal = $_GET['finaltotal']`.

Also, regarding your big if/elseif block of code, I would recommend using a switch statement instead if you are going to keep your code as is.

```
switch($key)
{
    case 'finaltotal':
        //do stuff
        break;
    default:
        //do default
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you either can use $_GET/$_POST for the submited data, as fabrik pointed out, or (if for some reason you really only have your data in *$data*) can use the built in function [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/function.parse-str.php).

```
parse_str($data, $fields);
foreach($fields as $key => $field) {
  foreach ($cart->get_contents() as $item) {
    if($key == ...) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

And if I correctly understand what you are doing here, you need to move the `break 3;` out of your for loop:

```
elseif($key == "finaltotal") {
  $finaltotal = $value.",";
  $final = explode(",",$finaltotal);

  for($i = 0; $i < count($final); $i++){
    $totalf = $final[$i];
  }
  break 3;
}
```

Comment: Hey there @slosd when i am doing here is that i am stop the if loop from creating duplication, without the break i keep on getting 100.00100.00100.00